# razor syntax issue on server deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have recently started razor development,so not yet familier with nitti gritties of cshtml yet but quite familier with syntax.

This is something strange i encountered on server.

On My Local visual studio environment this works well.

```
@{
  @Html.DropdownList()
}
```

So I uploaded the same on server which throws me, { not closed, parser error.

after lot of troubleshooting, what worked was changing it to this.

```
@{
   Html.DropdownList()
}
```

Second way is probably how it should be done. but why does first one works on local environment but will not do on server? Any clues?

Comment: I would also add that inside a server-code block (which is what @ { } represents) you must end all statements with a semicolon, just like in regular server code (because whatever is within such a block IS regular server code)

Comment: Regarding your question, I would think the 1st usage should be actually throwing an error...(once you declare a server-code block, you need not (and the compiler treats it as an error) indicate again that you are executing a server statement).

Answer (score 0):

It should be done like @Html.DropdownList()